# The rationale behind Falsy values

Tags: python, haskell, boolean

I'm wondering what the arguments for/against Falsy values are. On what principles would you decide to add or exclude them from a language? Are there any problems you could see them causing off-hand?

For users of languages that support Falsy values:

- Where specifically have you used them to your advantage?
- Where have you had unpleasant run-ins with them?
- Are there any rules or finer points in your language/project/team about where it's appropriate or inappropriate to use them?

For users of other languages:

- Have you ever seen a situation where you've thought "I wish I could use a Falsy value here"?

I'm tagging the question `haskell` and `python` because AFAIK those two represent opposite ends of the spectrum (Haskell demanding `Bool`s when you use `if`, and Python treating `None` and some "empty" values as Falsy), but feel free to talk about your experience from other languages. Just mention where on the spectrum they stand.

Comment: I'd think the extreme falsey language would be javascript not python . . .

Comment: @WyattBarnett: JavaScript got it from C, where **anything** can be a Boolean, including a freaking *assignment statement.*

Comment: @MasonWheeler : ceratainly true, on the other hand http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/truthy-falsey/

Comment: @WyattBarnett: Yeah, those are essentially the same rules that C follows, with the exception that you can't "box" a number in an object and get `Number(0) == true` the way you can in JS.  (At least, not as a language feature.)

Comment: @MasonWheeler - JS has the following Falsy values: `0`, `""`, `undefined`, `null` and `NaN`, while Python has `0`, `None`, `[]`, `{}`, `()` and `""`. I don't use C very much, so I'm not sure how it compares. The "anything as a boolean" is not an exclucively C thing either though; Common Lisp also lets you put anything in the test portion of an `if` or `when`, but only something that evaluates to `NIL` (which represents the empty list) will be treated Falsily.

Comment: @MasonWheeler: there's an interesting footnote in the C standard regarding boolean conversion: "When any scalar value is converted to `_Bool`, the result is 0 if the value compares equal
to 0; otherwise, the result is 1." Footnote: "_NaNs do not compare equal to 0 and thus convert to 1._"

Comment: @Mat: Interesting.  I wasn't aware of that footnote.

Comment: @Inaimathi: Yeah, but Lisp (and JavaScript, for that matter) has an excuse for that behavior: it's dynamically typed.  C isn't.

Comment: @MasonWheeler - Fair enough.

Comment: @MasonWheeler At least Common Lisp gives you a chance to provide static type information, if you want (and some compilers are pretty good at type inference).

Comment: @Vatine: And most modern statically-typed languages (with C being a big exception) give you a way to optionally use some sort of late-bound variables.  That doesn't change the basic fact that Lisp fundamentally is a dynamically-typed language and the statically-typed languages with this feature aren't.

Answer (score 2):

I use them to my advantage in Javascript all the time. In Javascript, the falsy values are `undefined`, `null`, `false`, `NaN`, `0` and `""`

It is just much easier to read:

```
if( !str ) {

}
```

instead of

```
if( str == null || str.length() == 0 ) {

}
```

or `str == null || str.equals("")` or bunch of other just as bad equivalents that you need to use in Java.

I do recall an instance where I was bitten by this, doing `x || y`, when a certain falsy value was desirable as `x`. But this is very rare.

---

However, the check is relatively sane in Javascript. Consider PHP, where additionally the string `"0"`, an empty array or, and I quote:

> SimpleXML objects created from empty tags

are considered falsy values. Also, `NaN` is truthy in PHP! So in this mess of completely arbitrary inconsistency, I wouldn't find the truthy/falsy concept
as good.

Comment: I consider "if( !str )" to be bad style. You are not making it clear what kind of value you have here, and if you have null for some reason while it should always be a boolean, the code will happily continue running.

Comment: @JeroenDeDauw it should be a null, undefined, or string. If it's not, it's the callers fault - this is how we think in Javascript culture anyway.

Comment: I do prefer static typing (even though my main lang is PHP), so you might be right on this being a cultural difference.

Comment: @JeroenDeDauw yes, it's basically the good old "The code should protect the programmer from themselves" vs "the programmer is a responsible adult" :P Depending on situation, either one can be the right approach.

Comment: JS also does some odd things with regard to `"0"`. Specifically, `"0" == 0`, but `!!"0"`. Which leads to the very odd situation that `"0" == 0 && 0 == "" && "0" != ""`. Once you've decided that 0 is Falsy, and that a number should compare to its stringified version under `==`, making `"0"` Falsy seems more consistent, if anything. Thanks for the insight.

Comment: @Inaimathi yes, `==` or `!=` in Javascript is a different game altogether, `if ( a == false )` is not the same as `if ( !a )` or other plain boolean conversions like in `a || b` or `a && b`.

Comment: "`str == null || str.equals("")` or bunch of other just as bad equivalents that you need to use in Java."  IMO that's a flaw in the Java language.  If the empty string was `null`, and not a separate value, you wouldn't have that problem.

Comment: @MasonWheeler - That begs the sequence question though: do you go the Python route and declare that empty sequences in general are Falsy, or do you treat String as special among them? Also, at that point, shouldn't you provide some facility to your users to define their own Falsies (since things other than the standard library sequences can be empty)?

Comment: @Inaimathi: Sorry, I guess I wasn't really clear with that.  There are two different concepts here.  I don't think that, in a strongly typed language, anything but the value `false`, of type Boolean, should be evaluate as "false".  The way that Java (and .NET) screw strings up by allowing you to have a string that contains no information, and yet is not the same as `null` (the constant that means "no information"), thus making checks for existence that much more complicated, is completely unrelated to the "falsy-ness" issue.

Comment: @MasonWheeler - Hm. So in Java/.NET, the empty string and the null string are distinct values? That's a bit odd. You're right though; that's a separate issue.

Answer (score 2):

Haskell too has the concept of falsy and I use them all the time.

Assume I have a handful of values and I need to fail if any one of those values are "false" (bools would be false, lists would be empty...). I can use the Maybe monoid to easily check if any of them are considered false based on their type.

True, the "if" statement in Haskell still only allows a boolean test condition, But Haskell makes it easy enough to create your own control structures to circumvent the problem.

The key is that in Haskell they are completely type checked so you know exactly what's happening. I've longed for them in C# but got around it by just explicitly checking for "false"

Answer (score 2):

In Python it's more of a `something` vs `nothing` concept, and it's incredibly convenient, plus much more readable, to have one's custom classes set to show as `nothing` (`False`) if they don't have a meaningful value when used in boolean tests.

Nearly all my own classes support it (lot's of container-type classes).

Answer (score 2):

The problem with "falsy" values is that they inevitably lead to ambiguities between in- and out-of-bounds responses: cases where an operation returns a "falsy" value that could mean either failure to produce an answer or success at producing an answer whose value is the "falsy" value.

One familiar example would be Java's `Map<K,V>.get(K key)` method, which returns `null` in two situations:

1. The map doesn't have an entry for the key you asked for.
2. The map has an entry that maps that key to `null`.

Contrast Haskell, where not only are `a` and `Maybe a` different types, but also `Maybe (Maybe a)` and so on.  In Haskell, if you need to (and most of the time you don't), you can distinguish between `Nothing` ("outer" failure) and `Just Nothing` ("inner" failure).

Comment: I'm kinda new to functional programming (via F#, not Haskell) but I thought that it was a requirement for `Monad a` to equal `Monad (Monad a)` (from here: http://ericlippert.com/2013/03/04/monads-part-four/). That is, amplifying an amplified type, produces the same amplified type. Considering that Maybe is a monad... Does that apply?

Comment: No, `Monad m => m (m a)` does not have to be isomorphic to `Monad m => m a`, and is only so in special cases.  There just needs to exist a `join :: Monad m => m (m a) -> m a` operation that obeys the `Monad` laws. Usually monads are explained in terms of `>>=`, which applies an `a -> m b` function "inside" the monad and then collapses the result, but the two operations can be factored out; `ma >>= f = join (fmap f ma)`. And collapsing, in general, destroys some information; `Maybe` is one example, another one would be `concat :: [[a]] -> [a]`, which destroys the *grouping* of the nested list.

Answer (score 1):

> On what principles would you decide to add or exclude them from a language?

I don't think that's the right question. Every language designer has something in mind when they design their language, and that often will dictate some of the answers.  For example, if you are designing for type-safety, then you won't allow numbers to be true or false. If you are designing for "easy scripting", you will allow lots of short-cuts.

For example, SQL treats NULL and false as so different that you have to use different operators on them ("is null" vs "= false"). Ruby thinks 0 is true, but Perl thinks it's false.

In Ruby, the set of things that are false is small enough to be easy to remember (Just false and nil).

> Where specifically have you used them to your advantage?

When picking up default values from various places:

```
my_name = env.name || command_line_swich.name || default_name
value = config['value'] || raise("no value found")
```

> Are there any problems you could see them causing off-hand?

Yes. In Perl, doing the above with numbers is a bad idea (because `0` could be valid, but will be ignored because it's false). Even in Ruby, it breaks when you have boolean values.

> Are there any rules or finer points in your language/project/team about where it's appropriate or inappropriate to use them?

Not really. We use them wherever we can get away with it, which proves their value.